# How to make an ImageView take up the entire screen?

Tags: android, imageview

I am building an android application. I have dropped in an `ImageView` in my activity. The image centers itself in the middle leaving strips of white background on all four sides. I have used `Toggle Height` and `Toggle Width` but it does not help. I need the image to cover up the entire screen with no background visible. Kindly refer to the screenshot below.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Why don't you just set the image to be the 'background' of your `Activity`? Use either `android:background` in your XML layout file or use `setBackground(...)` programatically.

Comment: I think beacuse of your relative/linear layout has a padding check your layout

Comment: @Squonk : Gr8! Worked :)

Comment: check your image.it may have transparent or white border.Kishan Dhamat answer is correct.

Answer (score 5):

Change to this:

```
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/icon" />
```

If you have given margin or padding then remove it from layout.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I achieved full page image background in my app with background.png:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

   ---- Other widgets here on top of the image ------
</LinearLayout>
```